# Examples of neighbourhood of a point

Tags: general-topology

I am learning what a neighbourhood of a point $x$ is in the context of topology. I would like to know if the following is correct:

Let $T=[0,2]$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,T,[1/3,1/2],[1,3/2]\}$ be the topology on $T$.

The definition of a neighbourhood of a point $x$ in my textbook is the following:

A *neighbourhood* of $x\in T$ is a set $H\subset T$ such that $x\in U \subset H$ for some $U\in\mathcal{T}$. An *open neighbourhood* of $x\in T$ is an open set $U$ (i.e. a set $U\in\mathcal{T}$) that contains $x$.

So by this definition, I would like to know if the following is true (for the sets I defined above):

Let $x=2/3$. Then $H=[0,1]$ is a neighbourhood. $H_1=[1/3,2/3]$ is a neighbourhood. $H_2=[0.4,1]$ is not a neighbourhood because it doesn't contain any of the open sets from $\mathcal{T}$.

So until now, $H,H_1$ are just neighbourhoods. If we set $x=0.4$, then the set $H_3=[1/3,1/2]$ is an *open neighbourhood* of $x$.

Do I understand everything correctly?

Comment: Your $\mathcal T$ is not a topology on $T$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why not? It satisfies the properties:

(T1) $T$ and $\emptyset$ are open

(T2) the finite intersection of open sets is open:

Every finite intersection is open in $\mathcal{T}$

(T3) arbitrary union of open sets are open

Comment: You're missing $[\frac13, \frac12] \cup [1, \frac32]$ as an open set.

Comment: Union of the two closed intervals in the definition does not belong to it. Even you include it make $\mathcal T$ a topology your answers are wrong. $[0,1]$ is  not a neighborhod of $x$.

Comment: @user $\mathcal T$ doesn't satisfies $(T_3)$, the union of $[1/3,1/2]$ and $[1,3/2]$ is not in $\mathcal T$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{\emptyset,T,[\frac13,\frac12],[1,\frac32]\}$ is merely a *base* for the topology, you need the union $[\frac13,\frac12] \cup [1,\frac32]$ to be in $\mathcal T$ as well.

With that addition a neighbourhood of $N$ of $\frac32$ is precisely a subset that contains $[1,\frac32]$ as a subset, which is the smallest open subset of $\mathcal T$ that contains $\frac32$ (and which exists in a space with only finitely many open sets, as here).

For $\frac23$ the *only* neighbourhood is $T$ itself. No other open subset contains it.

Comment: Okay, so from this question I also got to know that the unions of the subsets is also contained in a topology - a thing I was confused about. So let for example $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,T,[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}],[1,\frac{3}{2}],[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\cup [1,\frac{3}{2}]\}$. Let $x=\frac{1}{4}$. Then $x$'s neighbourhood is the whole $T$ since no other set from $\mathcal{T}$ contains it. Let $x=1$. Then the sets $[1,\frac{3}{2}]$ and $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\cup [1,\frac{3}{2}]$ are both neighbourhoods of $x$, since they are both open sets which contain $x=1$. Did I get this right?

Comment: @user yes, they are, in fact any superset of $[1,\frac32]$ is a neighbourhood of $x=1$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you very much